# Limit total size of inflight iot message

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am using IoTHub device client SDK on an embedded device. The application will send telemetry message to iot hub periodically. The iot device connect to a wireless router and wireless connect to internet via WAN port.

When the wireless router lost internet connection, iot device will not get notified immediately about the disconnection. It takes about 60s to get notified, before that iot device will continue to send telemetry message with IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendEventAsync(), all those message get queued in SDK layer and eat memory. Since it's on embedded device with limited resource, memory get eaten up and cause program been killed by a lower memory killer app.

Is there way to specified total size of iot message can be queued in sdk layer? If exceed this quota, IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendEventAsync() will failed immediately.

Actually this is also needed for normal scenario too. When iot device send message, seems message been queued in low layer and get flushed out at certain time. I don't see any API that can control the flush. That create another problem, even when there is internet connection, from application level, there is no control of how many message been queued and how long it been queued, in turn, app has no control of how much memory been used by process. On my device, there is system monitor that will kill process use too much memory.

Answer (score 2):

The question is what do you do even in that case if the message failure occurs in the case that the queue is full? Do you lose the information then because of lack of storage capacity? From the IoT perspective, I would recommend in this case to consider if your device is reliable IoT device to handle these edge cases as well. And also knowing the limits of the devices, and knowing how long it can be without the internet connection helps to mitigate these risks from your application, not SDK.

From the GitHub, default sendMessageAsync method throws timeout exception in case your message sending fails, unless you have some kind of retry policies implemented(according to the documentation C SDK does not allow custom retry policies 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-reliability-features-in-sdks).

According to the documentation in case of connection failure based on the retry policy(if you have set it), SDK will try to initiate connection this way or that way and queue the messages created in the meantime:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/doc/connection_and_messaging_reliability.md

So, an expectation here is that SDK does not take responsibility for the memory limits. This is up to the application to deal. Since your device has some limitations, I would recommend implementing your own queuing mechanism(maybe set no-retry as a policy and that way avoid queuing). That way you have under the control what will happen in the case that there is no internet connection and have under the control memory limitations. Maybe your business case accepts that you calculate an average value and instead of 50 you store 1 message over the time etc..

If this something you do not like, the documentation says also that you set the timeout for the queue - maybe not the memory limit but timeout yes, so maybe you can try to investigate this a bit deeper:

"There are two timeout controls in this system. An original one in the iothub_client_ll layer - which controls the "waiting to send" queue - and a modern one in the protocol transport layer - that applies to the "in progress" list. However, since IoTHubClient_LL_DoWork causes the Telemetry messages to be immediately* processed, sent and moved to the "in progress" list, the first timeout control is virtually non-applicable.

Both can be fine-tuned by users through IoTHubClient_LL_SetOption, and because of that removing the original control could cause a break for existing customers. For that reason it has been kept as is, but it will be re-designed when we move to the next major version of the product."